# Issue installing Ubuntu on HP mini 2133

Tags: installation, 13.04, lubuntu, hp

I am trying to install Ubuntu (and Lubuntu) 13.04 on a HP mini 2133, and when I boot from the usb disk I get the folloring messages:

```
udevd[99]: timeout: killing '/sbin/modprobe -bv pci:v00001106d00005372sv000103Csd00003030bc01sc01i8f' [224]
```

[image]

the number in the square brackets vary every time I try to boot from the live USB installer.
After a lot of those lines and some other messages in the end, the loading screen shows (the screen with four dots blinking), but it stays for a long time, and then the screen just turns black.
Any idea what this can be caused by?

Comment: Try booting from an Lubuntu 12.04 or set different boot parameters see --> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what that code means, but if you try installing the 64 bit version of 13.04 on a processor that has 32 bit architecture it won't work. Your VIA C7-M 1.6 GHz Ultra Low Voltage processor is single core and I can't seem to locate any specs that say it has a 64 bit instruction set, so it might be only a 32 bit processor, every reference I found said it was manufactured around April of 2005, I have older computers than that which support 64 bit, but they're not low voltage technology and yours seems to have come standard with XP or Vista with a non-specific Linux option. I don't recall if xp and vista were available in both 32 and 64 bit version as the last version of windows I used was xp.

I would suggest trying to install with the 32 bit 13.04 if you're not already... I hope it helps

Philip

Comment: Hej Philip,
Thanks for your answer. The installation I tried was i386 as I found that the VIA processor uses the x86 instruction set. So I doubt that this is the cause of the problem. What it is, I don't know.